# Soundcloud OAuth2 API: Getting invalid_scope error after user connection

Tags: oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I'm trying to implement Soundcloud connect and having a weird issue.

First thing I do is send my users to

```
https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http://myredirecturl.example.com&state=RANDOM_STRING&display=page&response_type=code&scope=email
```

When users connect they get redirected to

```
http://myredirecturl.example.com?error=invalid_scope&error_description=The+requested+scope+is+invalid%2C+unknown%2C+or+malformed.&state=RANDOM_STRING
```

The same happens if I use `scope=*`.

However, if I use `scope=non-expiring` it lets me go through, but I need the users email and that type of scope doesn't have enough grants.

I thought it had something to do with my app being in development mode, but [Osman at Soundcloud said it doesn't](https://twitter.com/soundcloudapi/status/232898121162706944).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'email' scope is not available to all integrations. It's used for a few custom integrations that have provided us with accepted terms of service / privacy policies. There is no way to get a user's email address using the SoundCloud API.

You should however be able to use the '*' scope to get an expiring access token. I'll check with our app team to see why this is giving you an error. I'll edit my answer once I have more information there.

For your purposes, I would stay with the 'non-expiring' scope and simply prompt a user for their email address (providing them with a way to agree to your terms of use / privacy information).

Comment: Thanks Paul. As I said via email: the idea was to let users log in to my site (which only requires an email and a password) using Facebook, Twitter and Soundcloud. In the process of implementation, I noticed Twitter won't give me users emails, so I discarded it because the whole point of letting users connect to one's site using an external service is to speed up the sign up process (isn't it?). If I would still need to ask them for their email address, then the point is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Using `scope=*` sometimes doesn't work because the url is not properly encoded. If you are getting this error while using the `*` wildcard, try properly encoding the url, using a function like [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) (for PHP).