# How to obtain email and birthday

Tags: ios, soundcloud

the "problem" ist that I want to have the email and birthday from my logged in user. I can get the name,location,... quite easily, but I don't know how to get the email and birthday.
Someone any idea?
regards

Comment: I changed the tags on your question to help draw in experts, and removed the keywords from the title, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for more info.

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852778/soundcloud-oauth2-api-getting-invalid-scope-error-after-user-connection

Comment: OK then it's not possible to get the email over the API.

Answer (score 0):

SoundCloud users don't have to enter their birthdays, so this information is also not in the API.